# Is there any way to use TCP/IP communication between a BBB and PC connected only by USB cable?

Tags: python, tcp, embedded, usb

Is there anyway to use TCP/IP communication between a Beaglebone Black and PC connected only by USB cable?

I'm try to create an oscilloscope using a Beaglebone Black ADC connected to a computer using a USB cable.

I know that when I connect my BBB (Beaglebone Black) I can access it by its ip 192.168.7.2 and I see this device on my local network if I use ipconfig on cmd (I'm using Windows 10), and if I ping on this IP I receive the data. But on the Beaglebone side I cannot see my computer on its network or ping to my computer local address.

Also I tried to use a basic python socket connection tutorial between my PC and BBB, here (PC as server and BBB as client):

https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

And I receive connection denied on my BBB.

Just to remember, I'm not pretending to solve it using an Ethernet cable or WiFi module.

Comment: What IP do you use for your PC? It should be in the same net as BBB (192.168.7.xxx) because BBB knows only that address and does not know addresses of other interfaces of your PC.

Comment: Disparando 192.168.1.10 com 32 bytes de dados:
Resposta de 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128
Resposta de 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128
Resposta de 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128
Resposta de 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still working on DHCP via RNDIS and Gadget Ethernet on Arch Linux, but on Ubuntu it works flawlessly. You may need some additional commands, but the general idea is to enable Gadget Ethernet using g_ether on the beaglebone.

I am assuming that you are using Angstrom. You will likely need to modify [/etc/network/interfaces](http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/) and ensure that it is configured for DHCP.

```
[BeagleBone Black]
insmod g_ether
echo "g_ether" > /etc/modules-load.d/gadget_ethernet
iface usb0 inet dhcp (/etc/network/interfaces)
```

Connect to USB port on Ubuntu. Share the internet connection using Ubuntu (require IPv4 to complete). Ensure that you have the BeagleBone SSH service enabled and the port opened on both Ubuntu and BeagleBone.

```
[Ubuntu]
nmap 10.42.0.0/24
```

ssh to the IP address that Ubuntu gave to the BeagleBone via USB.

I have [Arch Linux Arm](http://www.archlinuxarm.org) installed. For your application, I recommend Arch Linux Arm, which installs without a graphical user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an outgoing ping so you know that a TCP/IP connection can be established. However that is an *outgoing* connection and you are wanting to accept and *incoming* connection.

Check your firewall settings on your development machine, if the incoming connection is denied there you will not be able to connect. The outgoing ping might make it through the firewall but the incoming connection can still be denied. Because you know you can connect I would recommend checking the firewall rules allow an incoming connection to be made.

If you need to debug further go and get [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and see what traffic is going over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a Static IP address in order for the BBB to use the USB Ethernet connection.

Derek Molloy explains it here: http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/

Comment: Update:  I had the same problem with trying to ping from beagle bone black rev C to my windows laptop. Windows firewall by default has a rule enabled to block all incoming ICMP packets. So what you need to do is go to:
Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules and enable File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request for Public)